unable to integrate custom indicators/studies using highcharts
i'm working on a forex broker an trying to integrate custom indicator using highcharts library in NEXTJS but unable to come across a documentation for such
i initially used trading view but seem like to integrate an indicator one will need to go for a paid package which is high so how can i handle same with highcharts if not what other library could i try out for like stock/forex market data
below is the code
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'
import patternFill from "highcharts/modules/pattern-fill";


    
    const fetchHighchartData = async () => {
            setchartData({
                data: [],
                data_volume: [],
                show_data: false
            })
            const data = await fetch(
                'https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlcv.json'
            ).then(response => response.json());
            // split the data set into ohlc and volume
            const ohlc = [],
                volume = [],
                dataLength = data.length;
    
            for (let i = 0; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
                ohlc.push([
                    data[i][0], // the date
                    data[i][1], // open
                    data[i][2], // high
                    data[i][3], // low
                    data[i][4] // close
                ]);
    
                volume.push([
                    data[i][0], // the date
                    data[i][5] // the volume
                ]);
            }
            setchartData({
                data: ohlc,
                data_volume: volume,
                show_data: true
            })
    
            console.log(this)
        }
    
    
    
        useLayoutEffect(() => {
            
            fetchHighchartData()
           
    
        }, [])
    
        const options = {
            chart:{
                width:'1000',
                height:'600'
            },
               
            title: {
                text: 'My chart',
                
            },
    
            yAxis: [{
                height: '75%',
                width:'100%',
                labels: {
                  align: 'right',
                  x: -3
                },
                title: {
                  text: 'AAPL'
                }
              }, {
                top: '75%',
                height: '25%',
                labels: {
                  align: 'right',
                  x: -3
                },
                offset: 0,
                title: {
                  text: 'MACD'
                }
              }],
            
    
            series: [{
                type:'candlestick',
                id: 'aapl',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: chartData.data,
                
            },
            {
                type:'line',
                id: 'volume',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: chartData.data_volume,
                yAxis: 1
            }
            ]
        }
        console.log(options)
        
    
    
    
    
        return (
            <>
                {authData.logged_in ?
                    <Hero>
                        <main className={'bg-[#0B1215] lg:w-[100`enter code here`%] lg:h-[120vh]  max-xl:h-[100vh] lg:overflow-x-hidden md:h-[150vh] md:w-[100%] max-md:h-[100vh] max-md:w-[100%] '}>
    
                            <div className={'flex lg:w-full lg:h-[100%] md:h-full lg:flex-row p-2'}>
                                <aside className={' lg:flex lg:w-[25%] lg:h-[full] md:h-full p-5 md:hidden sm:hidden max-sm:hidden'}>
                                    <Rates handleGraphChange={handleGraphChange} />
                                </aside>
    
                                <div className={'flex lg:flex-row p-0 lg:w-[100%] lg:h-full md:w-[100%] md:h-[100%] sm:w-[100%] sm:h-[100%] max-sm:w-[100%] max-sm:h-[100%]  border-white bg-[#101720] max-md:flex-col max-xl:flex-col md:flex-col'}>
                                    <div className='flex flex-col w-[100%] h-[100%] p-2'>
    
                                        <div className='p-0 m-0 w-[100%] lg:h-[10%] flex justify-center items-center'>
                                            <FlipClockCountdown
    
                                                // to={new Date(expiry).getTime() + 24 * 3600 * 1000 + 5000}
                                                to={'2024-09-12'}
                                                className='h-full' title='Count-Down'
                                                labels={['DAYS', 'HOURS', 'MINUTES', 'SECONDS']}
    
                                                digitBlockStyle={{ height: 45, width: 25, backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'bg-[#0B1215]' }}
                                                // dividerStyle={{ color: 'white', height: 1 }}
                                                //  separatorStyle={{ color: 'red', size: '6px' }}
                                                labelStyle={{ fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 500, textTransform: 'uppercase', color: 'white', marginTop: '10%' }}
                                            />;
    
                                        </div>
    
    
                                        {/* 
                                        <div className='w-[100%] lg:h-[20%] md:h-[40%] sm:h-[50%] max-sm:h-[70%] p-2 grid lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-2 max-sm:grid-cols-2  place-items-center' >
                                            <Filter />
                                        </div> */}
                                        <div   className='p-0 flex overflow-y-hidden justify-center items-center lg:w-[100%] lg:h-[90%] max-lg:w-[100%] max-lg:h-[70%] md:w-[100%] md:h-[70%] max-md:h-[100%] sm:w-[100%] sm:h-[100%] max-sm:w-[100%] max-sm:h-[100%]  '>
                                            {chartData.show_data ?
                                            
                                                <HighchartsReact
                                                    highcharts={ Highcharts }
                                                    options={options}
                                                    constructorType={'stockChart'}
                                                    className="[w-100%] h-[100%]"
                                                    
                                                />
                                                
                                                :
                                                <span className="loading loading-bars text-white loading-lg"></span>
    
                                                
                                            }
    
    
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    
    
    
    
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
    
                        </main>
                    </Hero>
    
                    :
                    router.push('/')
    
                }
    
    
    
            </>
        )


It's possible to integrate the Highcharts with Next.js through react wrapper. You can read more about it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official#highcharts-with-nextjs
In terms of creating a custom indicator there are some docs and tutorials here:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/custom-technical-indicators
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/creating-custom-technical-indicators-financial-charts/


yea i have integrated it successfully just adding custom indicator a bit not clear for react or next
but i understand the process  for normal js with cdn
just need a documentation strictly on next or react for indicators

Thanks for the feedback, we'll think about adding a separate tutorial of how to proceed in react/next.js

Hello chudy any feedback on this?

Unfortunately, there's no update yet, but it's on our backlog.
